# EF Code First - mapping two foreign key columns in child table to the same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say you have a table of road mile-marker points (mile-markers are signs placed every mile on US highways). Then you have a second table of spans between these mile markers. The Span table has two **int** columns `StartMileMarkerId` and `EndMileMarkerId` which are foreign keys referencing MileMarker `Id` column; These are the tables;

tblMileMarkers

```
    [Table("tblMileMarkers")]
    public class MileMarker
    {
        public MileMarker()
        {
            Spans = new HashSet<Span>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DbGeography Location { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Span> Spans { get; set; }
    }
```

tblSpans

```
    [Table("tblSpans")]
    public class Span
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int StartMileMarkerId { get; set; }
        public int EndMileMarkerId { get; set; }

        public virtual MileMarker MileMarker { get; set; }
    }
```

If it was only one foreign key (`StartMileMarkerId`), I could configure the one-many relationship in the DbContext with Fluent Api as below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Span>().HasRequired(s => s.MileMarker) 
                .WithMany(m => m.Spans) 
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.StartMileMarkerId);
```

How can I map these 2 columns (`StartMileMarkerId` and `EndMileMarkerId`) to the same primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 foreign keys, you need 2 collection navigation properties in `MileMarker` and 2 reference navigation properties in `Span`. Something like this:

*MileMarker class:*

```
public virtual ICollection<Span> StartSpans { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Span> EndSpans { get; set; }
```

*Span class:*

```
public virtual MileMarker StartMileMarker { get; set; }
public virtual MileMarker EndMileMarker { get; set; }
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Span>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.StartMileMarker) 
    .WithMany(m => m.StartSpans) 
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.StartMileMarkerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Span>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.EndMileMarker) 
    .WithMany(m => m.EndSpans) 
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.EndMileMarkerId);
```

P.S. If your idea is to have `ModelMarker.Spans` collection mapped to spans with either start or end marker being this marker, it's just not possible.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have only one foreign key column f9ror startspan and endspan?

Comment: @mko It's a linking table, so no, they has to be two.

Comment: What if you use an abstract class and have two separate data tables?